# String Manipulation in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Can anyone give me a complete list of string manipulation function in Microsoft SQL Server (2000 or 2005)?

(I don't need a lecture about doing all my string processing in the presentation layer.   And, I don't need a list of MySQL string functions.)

Thanks!

Comment: A quick google search gave me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx but that's for 2008.  Are there any differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[String Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I had seen that page but totally missed the box in the upper right part of the page with a link to the 2005 version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN and Google are your friends

[here is the 2008 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx), drill down to your specific flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the msdn list I noticed that [HashBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) is missing.  I suppose it falls under a different category, but it's definitely an operation performed on a string, and useful to know about.